# centos: nginx + thin webserver, incoming connections not allowed

Tags: centos, nginx

I setup a fresh CentOS 5 install, compile nginx from scratch and am using thin as the rails server.

If I visit the ip adress on the LAN: (for example) `1.2.3.4` I get the website not found error.

However, I can ssh into the machine. If I use links to visit the ip address, I get the landing page.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I ran `system-config-securitylevel` and then was able to change the security settings to allow incoming connections.

Answer (score 0):

Your firewall is probably blocking it.  To open access for port 80 to all traffic, run (as *root*):

```
iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

To only open traffic for your LAN (or any arbitrary block of IP addresses), add a `-s` argument with the IP block in CIDR notation.  For instance, to open Port 80 for 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255:

```
iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

To make that change persist across reboots, add all of the arguments (e.g. everything except `iptables`) to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, just before the line that begins `-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT`.

Comment: tried that, but no luck. thanks anyways.